# Target Device ID (0x0) does not match expected Device ID (0x18620000). dsPIC33

Tags: pic

I have a problem with dsPIC33EP256MU810. I'm using PICkit3 and after I want to load the program to the MCU, MPLAB shows the following message:

```
Target Device ID (0x0) does not match expected Device ID (0x18620000).
```

I searched some solutions on forums, everything is OK but on VCAP (10uF tantalum) pin I have no voltage. It may be 1.8V, but I have 0 V.

PGC and PGD are working normally. I have this problem on 2 prototype PCBs.

[image: Schematics]

Comment: And is the power working?

Comment: Your programmer is just not able to detect your device. So either the programming lines are not well connected, or the power is not supplied. Or the chip is dead.

Comment: When this happens to me it's because of poor connection between chip and programmer, or because I forgot to power my board/chip.

Comment: Somewhere in the manual it doesn't say - Target Device ID(0x0) = Device not found = hardware issue. It means absolutely no communication has happened between the programmer and chip.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem: I forgot to connect USB3V3.

Comment: I guess this answer might be useful to others because it shows a working programming configuration, but maybe next time you're here mark this as accepted so it doesn't keep getting bumped by the automatic community user process.